# jQuery Validate validates but doesn't submit

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I've been looking at dozens of different versions of this question and trying dozens of different recommendations, but I cannot get this to work.

I am using jQuery validate to validate my form.  If I hit the submit button without filling in the form, all the required fields are flagged and the proper messages displayed.  So, I know the validation if working.

However, if I fill in all the fields and hit submit, nothing appears to happen.  I get no console messages or errors.  I added an alert, but that doesn't get triggered either.

My form looks like this:

```
    <form id="sportsAppRequest" name="sportsAppRequest" action="https://childrenshospital.secure.force.com/HC4__WebFormProcessor" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" class="reference" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.RecordTypeId" name="HC4__Inquiry__c.RecordTypeId" value="012G00000010652IAA" />
        <input type="hidden" class="picklist" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Status__c" name="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Status__c" value="Open" />
        <input type="hidden" class="string" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Subject__c" name="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Subject__c" value="Sports Med App Appointment Request" />
        <input type="hidden" class="picklist" id="Patient.LeadSource" name="Patient.LeadSource" value="Web Form: Sports Med App Appointment" />
        <input type="hidden" class="picklist" id="Patient.HC4__MostRecentLeadSource__c" name="Patient.HC4__MostRecentLeadSource__c" value="Web Form: Sports Med App Appointment" />
        <input type="hidden" class="string" id="DemandConnectForm" name="DemandConnect.Form" value="sportsAppRequest" />
        <label class="string" id="Patient.FirstName_label" for="Patient.FirstName">Patient First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="string required" id="Patient.FirstName" name="Patient.FirstName" value="" autocomplete="off" /><br/>
        <label class="string" id="Patient.LastName_label" for="Patient.LastName">Patient Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="string required" id="Patient.LastName" name="Patient.LastName" value="" autocomplete="off" /><br/>
        <label class="date" id="Patient.HC4__Birthdate__c_label" for="Patient.HC4__Birthdate__c">Patient Birthdate</label>
        <input type="text" class="date required" id="Patient.HC4__Birthdate__c" name="Patient.HC4__Birthdate__c" value="" /><br/>
        <label class="email" id="Patient.Email_label" for="Patient.Email">Contact Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" class="email required" id="Patient.Email" name="Patient.Email" value="" /><br/>
        <label class="phone" id="Patient.Phone_label" for="Patient.Phone">Contact Phone</label>
        <input type="tel" class="phone required" id="Patient.Phone" name="Patient.Phone" value="" /><br/>
        <label class="picklist" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__SubmittedOnBehalfOf__c_label" for="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__SubmittedOnBehalfOf__c">Relation to Patient</label>
        <input type="text" class="picklist required" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__SubmittedOnBehalfOf__c" name="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__SubmittedOnBehalfOf__c" value="" /><br/>
        <label class="textarea" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Comments__c_label" for="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Comments__c">Reason for Appointment Request</label>
        <textarea class="textarea required" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Comments__c" name="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Comments__c"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="sportsAppRequestSubmit" class="btn blue" value="Submit" class="disableOnClick" />
        <!-- <a href="/sportsmedapp/app/email/thanks" class="btn blue">Submit</a> -->
    </form>
```

My validation jQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // just for the demos, avoids form submit
  //jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
   // debug: false,
   // success: "valid"
  //});

  $('#sportsAppRequestSubmit').on('click', function(e) { // capture the <button> click
    e.preventDefault();              // stop any default <button> action
    $("#sportsAppRequest").submit(); // submit form (automatically validates)
  });

  // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
  // It has the name attribute "registration"
  $("#sportsAppRequest").validate({
    onsubmit: false,
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function(form) {  
      alert( "SUBMIT");
      if ($(form).valid()) {
         form.submit(); 
      }
      return false; // prevent normal form posting
    },
    // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      "Patient.FirstName": "required",
      "Patient.LastName": "required",
      "HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__SubmittedOnBehalfOf__c": "required",
      "HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Comments__c": "required",
      "Patient.HC4__Birthdate__c": {
        required: true,
        date: true
      },
      "Patient.Email": {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      "Patient.Phone": {
        required: true,
        phoneUS: true
      }
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      "Patient.FirstName": "Please enter your firstname",
      "Patient.LastName": "Please enter your lastname",
      "Patient.Email": "Please enter a valid email address",
      "Patient.HC4__Birthdate__c": "Please enter a valid date",
      "Patient.Phone": "Please enter a valid phone number",
      "HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__SubmittedOnBehalfOf__c":"Please enter your relationship to the patient, or self",
      "HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Comments__c": "Please enter the reason for your appointment"
    },
  });
});
```

Any help would be GREATLY appeciated!

Comment: Take out your `click` handler. The plugin does that automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried it both with and without.  Some of the answers I've seen on Stackoverflow explicitly use it, so I left it in just in case.  I've taken it out for now, but it appears to have no effect.

Comment: You have `onsubmit: false`. That disables the automatic validation during submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove your entire `click` handler function.  Any answer on SO that shows a `click` handler along with this plugin is likely mistaken in its implementation, or its form submission "button" is not a `type="submit"`.
2. Remove your `onsubmit: false` option as this would disable validation as triggered by the submission of the form.  [As per the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onsubmit), you'd only set this to `false` to *"use other events for validation"*.
3. You do not need `if ($(form).valid())` within the `submitHandler`.  [As per docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), the form is already valid at this point so there's no point in checking here.
4. If the only important part inside your `submitHandler` is `form.submit()`, then you can remove the `submitHandler` entirely, as that's already the default functionality of this plugin.

**Working for me:  [jsfiddle.net/7cut3s4r/](http://jsfiddle.net/7cut3s4r/)**

**NOTE**:  You do not need `class="phone required"` on your `input` element while  you're also declaring these same two rules within the `.validate()` method.  It's redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, @sparky!